# How can I fix the "fetch" proxy error in create-react-app project?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I am writing an app that can use mySQL database to store user information (login, registration).
The problem is that when I try to call a server from the frontend (via proxy in package.json), it returns me an 404 error. Frontend is based on a *create-react-app* template. I use *Axios* library on backend.

Screenshot is below.

[image]

(also you can see that some inputs are cleared automatically in Registration page when you try to type in something).

My *package.json* in `create-react-app` (I think there is something wrong exactly in *package.json*):

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Project on a Github: https://github.com/thesiv95/mysql-cra-01042020

Thanks for any help.

btw, author: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1hhL9z-fbU

thanks a lot if you see my message!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your server should run on port `5000` but you are making POST request to port `3000`.

Comment: I know. The point is that I send POST queries to 3000 and the proxy "copies" it to 5000. So I don't think about backend port at all